# Can't get meta information with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Any ideas why on a website I can't get `<meta>` informations ?

I'm using:

```
$.find("meta[name='description']").attr("content");
```

To get:

```
<meta name="description" content="My description">
```

Why I could not retrieve these datas ?

Any ideas ?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it worth pointing out that there *is no* [`$.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.find), which would explain it not working? You might consider `$('meta[name="description"]').attr('content')` though. If you're having trouble with jQuery, try reading the [API](http://api.jquery.com/), it's really very good.

Comment: Try $("head meta[name='description']").attr("content");. .find() works on jquery objects, not jquery itself.

Comment: When do you call the jQuery fragment?

Comment: @DavidThomas Works fine for me, e.g., http://i.imgur.com/M686qxa.png. Not that this is how I'd do it since it's redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass jQuery the selector directly and retrieve the value of the `content` attribute like so:

```
$('meta[name="description"]').attr("content");
```

Comment: This is the way to do it unless you specifically need to narrow where you look for the meta tag. Which you almost certainly don't.

Answer (score 1):

find it in head tag

```
 $("head").find("meta[name='description']").attr("content");
```